# Create a class in Magento [Best Practice]

Tags: php, magento

I have created a module in Magento. This module makes HTTP calls. I would like each HTTP response to be an object of a PHP Class, as I would like to run

```
$response->isError();
$response->getBody();
$response->getBodyJson();
// ... etc
```

Should I be creating a *Model* or *Helper* in this case ?

I am still figuring my way around Magento Architecture and Conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically model is the part of your application that defines its basic functionality behind a set of abstractions. Data access routines and some business logic can be defined in the model.

Considering above statement, I think you should create Model for this.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

**General**
If you need to save something in your database you should create a model for that and map your model on the database table(s).
If you want just to perform simple actions and don't save anything in the db, both could work, but I would go with a helper.
**Specific**
in your case, if you want the response to be an object and call different methods on it it should be a model.

Comment: Thanks ! Yes, I will be going with model itself.